# DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router, react-dates

I am new to Reactjs. I wanted to input date-range from user and pass it to second page(search) but I got the error(DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History'.) when I pass states endDate and startDate.It works fine when I pass any sample string(example - startdate:"sample").
Please help me to get rid of this error.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "react-bootstrap";
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-dates";
import "react-dates/initialize";
import "react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css";

function Filters() {
  const [dateRange, setdateRange] = React.useState({
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
  });
  const [focus, setFocus] = React.useState(null);
  const { startDate, endDate } = dateRange;
  return (<>
          <DateRangePicker
            startDatePlaceholderText="Check-in"
            endDatePlaceholderText="Check-out"
            startDate={startDate}
            endDate={endDate}
            numberOfMonths={1}
            onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) =>
              setdateRange({ startDate, endDate })
            } 
            showClearDates={true}
            focusedInput={focus}
            onFocusChange={(focus) => setFocus(focus)}
            startDateId="startDateMookh"
            endDateId="endDateMookh"
            minimumNights={1}
          />
        
          <Link to={{ pathname: "/search", state: {
                startdate: "startdate",
                enddate: endDate,
                },}}>
            <div className="search">
              <p>Search</p>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </>
  );
}

export default Filters;
```

This is second page (search)

```
import React from "react";
import Hotellist from "./components/hotellist";
import Filters from "./components/filters";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

function List() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const {startdate, enddate} = location.state;
  console.log(startdate, enddate);
  return (
   <>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I could find is that startDate and endDate are not just dates. They hold more data than that. To get only date or to send data to other page use moment

```
import moment from "moment"

Send it like this

startdate: moment(startDate).format("yyyy-MM-dd")
```